# Unit group of Laurent polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> If $R$ is a domain, how do I prove that $R[X,X^{-1}]^*=\{uX^k:u\in R^*,k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cong R^*\times\mathbb{Z}$?

I have no idea where to begin with this proof.

Comment: Try $R[X,X^{-1}]^\ast \ni uX^k \mapsto (u,k) \in R^\ast \times \Bbb Z$.

Comment: @IvoTerek I will try and see how it goes, but can you post a full proof a little bit later if you could? Thanks! :)

Comment: Don't deface your question. It is disrespectful to the answerer to edit your question into nonsense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any nonzero element of $R[X,X^{-1}]$ can be written in a unique way as
$$
p(X)X^m
$$
where $p(X)\in R[X]$, with $p(0)\ne0$, and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. (Prove it, if you don't already know it.)

Since $X^m$ is invertible in $R[X,X^{-1}]$, if $p(X)X^m$ is invertible, then also $p(X)$ is. Now its inverse must be of the form $q(X)X^n$, with $q(X)\in R[X]$ and $q(0)\ne0$, so
$$
p(X)q(X)X^n=1
$$
If $n<0$, this becomes $p(X)q(X)=X^{-n}$ that's impossible (evaluate at $0$); if $n>0$ this is impossible either (evaluate at $0$). So $n=0$ and $p(X)q(X)=1$ in $R[X]$, hence the degree of $p$ is $0$. Therefore $p$ is a nonzero constant.

Conversely, any element of the form $rX^m$ with $r\in R$, $r\ne0$, is invertible in $R[X,X^{-1}]$.

The map
$$
rX^m\mapsto (r,m)
$$
is clearly an isomorphism $R[X,X^{-1}]^*\to R^*\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The degree is 2?

Comment: @JimmyP No. As $X^m$ is invertible in $R[X,X^{-1}]$, then also $p$ should be. But…

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see where this is headed